# MySQL select members that have more than *column value* records in table

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables set up:

```
MEMBERS

_________________________________________________
|memberid  |   firstname  | lastname  | sessions|
_________________________________________________
|1         |   john       | doe       | 1        |  
|2         |  Dave        | Smith     | 2        |
_________________________________________________

BOOKINGS
___________________________________
|id    |memberid  |   date    | time  | group |
___________________________________
|1     |1         |2016-04-19 | 08:00 | 1     |
|2     |2         |2016-04-18 | 13:00 | 4     |
|3     |1         |2016-04-15 | 18:00 | 3     |
_______________________________________________
```

I'd like to return the firstname and lastname of all members that have more than members.sessions records in the bookings table this week.

I have the php code to generate the two dates

$FirstDay = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('sunday last week'));

$LastDay = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('sunday this week'));

substituted into a where clause = where bookings.date between '$FirstDay' and '$LastDay'

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: wait maybe i misunderstood, you want to check whether members.session is more than the amount of bookings for that member?

Comment: updated my answer, i think that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, sessions, count(bookings.id) AS sum_bookings
FROM members
JOIN bookings ON bookings.memberid = members.memberid
WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY members.memberid
HAVING sessions > sum_bookings
```

Read more about `BETWEEN` [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)

or with your variables:

```
$query = "SELECT firstname, lastname, sessions, count(bookings.id) AS sum_bookings
FROM members
JOIN bookings ON bookings.memberid = members.memberid
WHERE date BETWEEN '".$FirstDay."' AND '".$LastDay."'
GROUP BY members.memberid
HAVING sessions > sum_bookings";
```

Be careful about inserting variables like this. It could make you vulnerable to SQL injections, better to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: That worked for me with a slight tweak due to misunderstanding as i wanted to know when sessions where less than number of rows, So i changed sessions > sum_bookings to sessions <= sum_bookings and it is no outputting the desired result. Many thanks

Comment: aaah, yeah i had some trouble understanding your first sentence ;) good luck on your project!